# How to check if a csv file has been uploaded in a drive daily and alert user if not?

Tags: windows, automation, batch-processing, power-automate, eventtrigger

I have been assigned a task of automating a manual activity which involves checking if a particular data file has been uploaded in a drive daily.The file is a .csv file added incrementally(once) every morning and named based on the date and time it has been uploaded.
In case the file is not present in the drive folder there should be a trigger alert to the stakeholders in the form of email.

What are the automation tools I can use to automate this particular activity?

My current plan is to write a java code that checks the folder.Using Jenkins I will run it everyday and trigger email alert in case a particular file is not present.
Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Where’s the drive the file is going to?

Comment: @Skin-It's a shared drive on network accessible on my machine.

Comment: So you're wanting to run it on your machine or is that risky? I would think it's risky if you're on holidays or not in the office.  I'm trying to get to the bottom of you infrastructure and what sort of solution you're ultimately looking for.  If you want it to be completely hands off then there are cloud options but you'll need to open up your network drive to a gateway or something.

Comment: @Skin I will deploy the solution on a windows server machine which had access to network drive.

Comment: There are a million ways to skin this cat, just do what you're doing.

Comment: Ok @skin.Apart from this can you suggest any other automation tools